# Error message converting PDF to JPG using imagemagick

Tags: linux, imagemagick, centos

Command:

```
convert small.pdf small.jpg
```

Output:

```
sh: gs: not found
convert: Postscript delegate failed `small.pdf': ZkQV.cache @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/638.
convert: missing an image filename `small.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.
```

Version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-05-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

File used: http://www.relacweb.org/menuconferencia/menu/manual-memorias.pdf

On Linux.

Comment: It looks like you don't have the `ghostscript` package installed.

Comment: I thought ghostscript depended on imagemagick, not the oposite. Do I have any chance of making it work without sudo access? (managed VPS, grr)

Comment: imagemagick uses the `ghostscript` package for handling the pdf format. Depending on your host, you can often install packages 'locally' to satisfy these requirements.